# How to see debug logs for JRE and/or GAE classes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

Is it possible to change logging level for JRE and/or GAE classes?

I tryed putting this into logging.properties file:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.level = ALL
```

I tryed to change level from code:

```
Logger.getLogger("sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection").setLevel(Level.ALL);
Logger.getLogger("com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch").setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

But so far i only see logs of my own app in the GAE console. I have no idea how to debug a problem that only happens in GAE but not in my local sandbox...(

Answer (score 0):

Differences between local and production environments usually can be easily found without logging from Google classes. For example for URLFetch it is 10 sec timeout. May be it will be better to describe the problem you are trying to debug.